# No "k-grid-content" is on table even after scrollable is set true

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

After setting "scrollable" property to true in kendo grid options, the kendo grid should render with a "k-grid-content" class in its table. This class helps with the scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

Add some code and perhaps a link to a Kendo dojo if you can recreate it.

It appears to be working according to this dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/IpoFiTil/111

grid code:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
              //removed for brevity
            },
            scrollable: true,
            columns: [
              //removed for brevity
            ]
          });
```

If I leave scrollable: true a div is inserted around the table that does get the class k-grid-content as shown below

```
<div id="grid" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-grid-display-block" style="height: 550px;">
  <div class="k-grid-content k-auto-scrollable" style="height: 347px;">
    <table role="grid" style="height: auto;">
      //removed for brevity
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

And if you set scrollable to false, the div with the k-grid-content class is removed:

```
<div id="grid" data-role="grid" class="k-grid k-widget k-grid-display-block" style="height: 550px;">
  <table role="grid" style="height: auto;">
    //removed for brevity
  </table>
</div>
```